# laravel not working without php artisan serve command

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am currently working on laravel 5.3. My team mate installed laravel on his machine using composer. In my machine i also have  installed composer, and installed a larvel project using laravel installer, which was installed by composer. Now when i got the archive file o fproject installed by my team mate on my machine i run 
`php artisan cache:clear`,
`php artisan route:clear`,
`php artisan key:generate`,
`php artisan serve` 
commands and clicked the link provided (i.e localhost:8000 ) in terminal,by this project is running fine but, but when i am  entering the url in the browser like
localhost\laravel\public it is not running correctly.

Comment: What happens when you go to Localhost:8000? That is the default one if I'm right!

Comment: when i was going to localhost:8000 it is working perfect.

Comment: it is good to say thanks on perfectly working answer :)

Comment: @Masood i didn't got my answer yet. My problem is that when i am clicking the link provided by the terminal (i.e localhost:8000 ) my project is working perfect.
But when i am manually inserting the path in url (i.e localhost/laravel/public) it is not working properly, also entering manually localhost:8000 in url is not workin.  :(

Comment: @rahulsnegi, are you making sure to include the port number (`:8000` in this instance) when you type the address?

Comment: Laravel is not running in your local server root directory. if you want to use `localhost/laravel/public` (port 80) then you will have to move the laravel folder into your server root folder.

Comment: @michel  I do have moved laravel inside  E:\\xampp\htdocs.

Comment: @Chris sorry but, i did'nt get your point, can you explain

Comment: @rahulsnegi yes in htdocs will run as you want

Comment: @Michel But its not working.
actually i do have other projects in htdocs of other frameworks like ci, cakephp,does it have anything to do with this.
my complete path of laravel project is :- E://xampp/htdocs/laravel

Comment: @rahulsnegi, if the server is accessible at `localhost:8000` you probably need to visit `localhost:8000/laravel/public`. The port number is significant. Furthermore, what does "it is not running correctly" mean?

Comment: You need to set up your webserver. Laravel doesn't do that for you.

Comment: @chris  By "running not correctly", I mean that project is loading but not who it should be. Design and other elements are destroyed.

Comment: @rahulsnegi, that is **very important information that you should have included in your original question**. Your static assets probably aren't being served properly. **Please be as specific as possible when asking questions here.** See [ask].

Comment: Make sure your JS and CSS link uses `{{ URL::asset('') }}` to link to CSS, images and JS

Comment: @ceejayoz i do have setuped my local server, but if there is anything to do specific for laravel. can you help me out with that.

Comment: Check this out http://tutsnare.com/how-to-install-laravel-on-windows-xampp/

Comment: @Chris apologies for the mistake. But i ended my question with words " not running correctly ". By the way thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @rahulsnegi, I know you ended your question with those words. That could mean any number of things. It's too general. Based on the comments almost everybody thought you meant, "I can't get my site to load". If you really mean, "the site loads, but my styles aren't working", please say that. Anyway, I'm glad everybody is on the right track now.

Comment: @Michel when going through the link, i understand that it will create a fresh project in my directory. which i have done already and running fine in all casses. Did i understand it right? 
if yes then, 
 what i want is to run a laravel project which have been coded  a bit.

Comment: Use `composer dump-autoload` in composer. It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project

Comment: i think your issue is in apache configure file ... i think you should change allowoverride none to allowoverride all in httpd.confg

Answer (score 0):

As local dev is always susceptible to configuration issues. I would also suggest your team look into a proper virtualization solution using vagrant/Homestead, More information and documentation available @ [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead)

The advantage is that once the project is configured you never need to worry about these system-specific occurrences and all team members can work on the same underlying system specs.

Note that you can use real domains (e.i project-name.dev.yourdomain.com) by just pointing them to the 10.x.x.x ip range.

Answer (score 0):

Just Give the permissions to these directories

1. storage
2. bootstrap/cache

and the work is done.